# Domain Driven Design | Invoking external services to enrich entity properties

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

For study purposes I have designed a product-service which allows to perform CRUD operations against a product entity made up by the following properties:

- string ID
- string Name
- decimal ListPrice
- decimal FinalPrice

the ID, the Name and the ListPrice are stored in the product-service's database, while the FinalPrice is retrieved by an external service, the price-card-service, which exposes the following endpoint: GET /price-card-by-id/{product-id} which returns an object containing the product's final price.

The Create and Update operations of the product-service don't allow to do anything with the product's FinalPrice, but when retrieving a Product it will have its FinalPrice if returned by the price-card-service

By now the logic of retrieving and setting the FinalPrice is handled withing the GetProductByIdRequestHandler:

```
public class GetProductByIdRequestHandler : IAppRequestHandler<GetProductByIdRequest, GetProductByIdResponse>
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;
    private readonly PriceCardServiceClient _priceCardServiceClient;

    public GetProductByIdRequestHandler(IProductRepository productRepository, PriceCardServiceClient priceCardServiceClient)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
        _priceCardServiceClient = priceCardServiceClient;
    }

    public async Task<OneOf<GetProductByIdResponse, IError>> Handle(GetProductByIdRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var product = await _productRepository.GetById(request.ProductId);
        
        if (product == null)
        {
            return new NotFoundError
            {
                Message = $"Could not find product {request.ProductId}"
            };
        }

        var priceCardList = await _priceCardServiceClient.ActiveAsync(product.Id, cancellationToken);

        if (!priceCardList.Items.Any())
        {
            product.FinalPrice = product.Price;
            return new GetProductByIdResponse(product);
        }
        var priceCard = priceCardList.Items.First();
        if (priceCard.NewPrice < 0)
        {
            return new PriceCardNewPriceLessThanZeroError
            {
                Message = $"Price {priceCard.NewPrice} for PriceCard {priceCard.Id} for Product {product.Id} must be greater or equal to 0"
            };
        }
        product.FinalPrice = ProductPrice.From(System.Convert.ToDecimal(priceCard.NewPrice));

        return new GetProductByIdResponse(product);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if DDD promotes a different way for handling this kind of operations, perhaps by injecting the PriceCardServiceClient into the Product entity and creating a readonly FinalPrice property which handles the logic.

What are the possible approches?

Answer (score 0):

It depends from your domain, mainly.

Is the **Product**, as a domain object, requiring this information? Then you could:

1. store it directly, requiring it before via the service,
2. obtain it every time you need the entity.

The first solution requires a 'update' process, that at least for each valid **Product**, aligns the stored value with the current valid one. The second one gives you the current value every time, but it also makes that part of the domain dependent from another service. In other words, you could not get the Product if the service *PriceCardServiceClient* is not responding. Or, you should manage this special case, once again with extra code.

If, instead, your domain entity doesn't require it, if you load/show/manage it is just related to the UI. Hence, using the DDD will not cause any change in the way you get this information.